# <html:link> pass parameters

Tags: struts

I want to pass a single parameter with holds a username through a  tag.

In the corrosponding action class I'm retreiving the parameter with request.getParameter() function, but I'm getting the value as null. here's my code

```
    <%
    String username="aniket";
    request.setAttribute("username",username);
    %>
 <html:link action="AllResidentInfo.do" paramName="username" paramProperty="username">All Resident's Info</html:link>
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3alink):

> paramId
>
> The name of the request parameter that will be dynamically added to
>   the generated hyperlink. The corresponding value is defined by the
>   paramName and (optional) paramProperty attributes, optionally scoped
>   by the paramScope attribute
>
> paramName
>
> The name of a JSP bean that is a String containing the value for the
>   request parameter named by paramId (if paramProperty is not
>   specified), or a JSP bean whose property getter is called to return a
>   String (if paramProperty is specified). The JSP bean is constrained to
>   the bean scope specified by the paramScope property, if it is
>   specified.

So it should be

```
<html:link action="AllResidentInfo.do" paramId="username" paramName="username"/>
```

Comment: Should my paramName contain the name of the jsp file which has the getter setter for "username" beacuse if i do so as you told me, its giving me the error as "  No getter method for property: "username" of bean: "username"

Comment: A JSP doesn't have getters and setters. I don't understand what you're asking. `paramId` is the name of the request parameter. `paramName` is the name of the request attribute containing the value of the parameter. So if paramId is "foo", and paramName is "bar", and you have a request attribute names "bar" which contains the string "hello", it will generate the link `AllResidentInfo.do?foo=hello`. So, the above with your scriptle code sample sould generate `AllResidentInfo.do?username=aniket`

Comment: ya, i did what you told me, but it is still giving me the error, could not find bean: username in any scope..

Comment: I don't see how that is possible, since the line just before the link tag is `request.setAttribute("username",username);`.